# Can a form submit be disabled if a HTML file input field is empty?

Tags: html, forms, file-upload

In a form which contains only a

```
<input id="fileInput" name="BugReport" type="file" />
```

input field, I would like to disable the Submit button if the file input is empty (no file was chosen yet). Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `required` attribute to the input. It'll only work in browsers that support it, so you should have a JavaScript alternative (`<form onSubmit="if(document.getElementById('fileinput').value == '') return false;">` or something along those lines).

Answer (score 0):

Checking for whether the file input's value should always work.

```
if (document.getElementById("fileInput").value == "") .....
```

the true path of the file will be obfuscated for security reasons, but the value should always return *something* when a file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript. The following code assumes you have given an `id` of "s" to the submit button of the form:

```
document.getElementById("fileInput").onchange = function() {
    if(this.value) {
        document.getElementById("s").disabled = false; 
    }  
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to have the submit button disabled to start off. For example:

```
<input type="submit" id="s" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this the best way is to have Javascript validate all the inputs as they are changed. So as the input gets changed (you can use the on change event) in Javascript enable or disable the button depending.

```
<input id="fileInput" name="BugReport" type="file" onchange="validateForm()"/>
```

This should call the javascript button which will check the input is it has a valid file and if so enable the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);

        $('#fileInput').change(function () {
            if ($('#fileInput').val().length == 0)
                $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
            else
                $('#submit').attr("disabled", false);
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="fileInput" name="BugReport" type="file" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" />
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you can add something like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="if (window.getElementById('fileInput').value == '') return false" />
```

or start with a disabled submit button and enable it when the file input is clicked and the value is different than the empty string.

check [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uguvof/3/edit#source) to see what the value of a file input is (its a 'fakepath' and the name of the file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 just add **required** inside input tag:

```
<input type='file' required />
```

Example:

```html
<form>
  <input type='file' required />
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```